# ESLint unexpected token in calculated object key

Tags: eslint, create-react-app

Using the latest rules from `eslint-config-react-app` we get the following linting error:

```
{
  [componentWidth > VIEW_DESKTOP && componentWidth <= VIEW_LARGE]: MAX_TICKS_LARGE
}
```

`error  Parsing error: Unexpected token`

The issue seems to be located at `<=` in the calculated key.

Does anyone know what's causing this to throw an error? The code should be legit.

**Update**: interestingly, the linting error doesn't show up in my IDE, only in the console.

**Update 2**: Seems to be an issue with eslint latest version rather than anything related to eslint-config-react-app. Using the eslint version specified by eslint-config-react-app works fine, just not with the latest version of eslint.

**Update 3**

To provide a better context for the problem, here's the function within which this code exists:

```
const getTicksToDisplay = (componentWidth) => {
    const truthMap = {
        [true]: MIN_TICKS_ON_SCREEN,
        [componentWidth > VIEW_LARGE]: MAX_TICKS_XLARGE,
        [componentWidth > VIEW_DESKTOP && componentWidth <= VIEW_LARGE]: MAX_TICKS_LARGE,
        [componentWidth > VIEW_TABLET && componentWidth <= VIEW_DESKTOP]: MAX_TICKS_DESKTOP,
        [componentWidth > VIEW_MOBILE && componentWidth <= VIEW_TABLET]: MAX_TICKS_TABLET,
        [componentWidth <= VIEW_MOBILE]: MAX_TICKS_MOBILE
    };

    return truthMap[true];
};
```

**Update 4**

The version of eslint at the time of asking this question was 3.11.1. The code works in eslint 3.8.1 and since asking this question, eslint 3.12.0 has been released (which I haven't been able to test against yet)

**Update 5**

Upon further testing it looks like this might be an issue with babel-eslint 7.1.1. I've raised an issue: https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/428

Comment: whats version of eslint your are using? also share more context of the code.

Comment: I get this error with v3.11.1

Comment: What more would you like to know about the code @Gyandeep ? There's an object with calculated keys that turns into a truth map. We return `someObj[true]` which gives us the last value in the map with a `true` key.

Comment: If i use the above code in any parser it will give me a parsing error: http://astexplorer.net/#/KWXRt4ScBK

Comment: The code in my question represents a javascript object. I think when pasting it directly into a parser, it becomes a code-block `{}` which doesn't parse. It parses if you put the object into a variable `const foo = {}`

Comment: http://astexplorer.net/#/KWXRt4ScBK/1

Comment: correct thats why i was asking for more context of the code. because you had parsing error thrown.

Comment: I'll add the whole function to the question for better context. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: I tried code on http://eslint.org/demo/ app and it worked fine their. Make sure the install of eslint your are using (global or from project node_modules folder) is updated.

Comment: They've updated eslint since I posted this question earlier today. Could be that their demo site uses the very latest version, I dunno. It works fine in eslint 3.8.1 (which is what i've reverted to) but doesn't work in 3.11.1. I'll see if there's still a problem when I use the new 3.12.0

Comment: Upon further testing I think this is an issue with babel-eslint 7.1.1. I've raised an issue with them. Thanks for helping @Gyandeep

Comment: FYI, ESLint supports features till ES2017 out of the box. You dont need babel-eslint for it. We also support experimental object-spread for jsx folks. http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

Comment: Might be a change I can submit to create-react-app since we're using their eslint config, eslint-config-react-app (outside of a CRA app). https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-react-app